# How can you change flavors in store-bought frosting?

Tags: substitutions, cupcakes, frosting

I'm in a time crunch and I bought pre-made frosting for some cupcakes I'm bringing to a potluck (I know, shame on me. The cupcakes are homemade at least.). Because I was rushing, I accidentally bought 'whipped cream frosting' when I was trying to go for 'cream cheese frosting'. I tried the frosting and I think it will be too sweet on my cupcakes. Is there any way I can fix this?? I think I have a tiny bit of cream cheese, could I add it to the frosting in some way to try to tone down the sweetness? My cupcakes are butternut squash spice (kind of a play on pumpkin spice) and they're rather sweet, which is why I was thinking the tang of cream cheese would go well.

Comment: If you're in a time crunch, i'd say go buy the right flavor of frosting. That being said, if you have time to alter the frosting, you can add whipped cream cheese directly into the frosting or whip some cream, add whipped cream cheese to the whipped cream, and add the mixture to the frosting, you'll end up having more frosting but the taste will be less sweet just like you want.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can certainly mix in something to change the flavor, and cream cheese sounds like a good option.  You will probably need to soften the cream cheese (microwave for a bit, but don't melt it), whip it, and then add in the store-bought frosting and whip until fully incorporated.  Depending on how much cream cheese flavor you like, I'd recommend something like 4 oz. per can of frosting.